# How to set up external routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hyperlink, routes

I have been making an Express application. I managed to get the `index` route working. I'm trying to add a new route called `cart`, which will bring the user to a shopping cart page. However, I can't manage to get my `cart` route to connect. I get a 404 error. Which is weird, because I set up my route the same as `index`.

I just noticed that when I open the link, it routes to `/shoppingcart.html`, instead of just `/shoppingcart`. Which makes no sense, since I don't have HTML files, and set up the link as `/shoppingcart` (as you can see below).
I am able to vist all the routes if i input them as /routename, however when i try to vist them from the index page, they all turn into /routename.html. Anyone know how to change this?

[image: List of files]

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var cart = require('./routes/cart');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
// Only needed if we use jade, we could use jade to route to html, but no point
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/shoppingcart', cart);
//app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
module.exports = app;
```

**car.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
// GET cart page. 
router.get('/shoppingcart', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('cart', { title: 'Shopping cart' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**layout.jade**:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    meta(name="description", content="")
    meta(name="author", content="")
    title Store Web page 
    // CSS
    link(href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
    link(href="/stylesheets/style_red.css", rel="stylesheet")
    link(href="/stylesheets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")
    // JS
    script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js")
    script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/angular-ui-router.min.js")
    script(src="script.js")
  body
    header
      // Navigation
      nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role="navigation")
        .container
          // Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display
          .navbar-header
            button.navbar-toggle(type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1")
              span.sr-only Toggle navigation
              span.icon-bar
              span.icon-bar
              span.icon-bar
            a.navbar-brand(href="index.html") Andrew Kralovec E-learning Studio
          // Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
          #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
            ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
              li
                a(href="about.html") About
              li
                a(href="fourm.html") Forum
              li
                // CART ROUTE 
                a(href="/shoppingcart") Cart
              li.dropdown
                a.dropdown-toggle(href="#", data-toggle="dropdown")
                  | Support
                  b.caret
                ul.dropdown-menu
                  li
                    a(href="tutorials.html") Tutorials
                  li
                    a(href="documents.html") Documents
                  li
                    a(href="common.html") Common questions
                  li
                    a(href="ticket.html") Kralovec support
              li
                a(href="contact.html") Contact
    // i like the layout options to jade 
    block content
  // Bottom page, wont work in the index jade 
  script(src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
  // Bootstrap Core JavaScript
  script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
  // Menu Toggle Script
  script.
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  footer
    | @John 2015
```

**cart.jade**:

```
extends layout
// shopping cart page 
block content
 .container
    table#cart.table.table-hover.table-condensed
    thead
        tr
        th(style='width:50%') Product
        th(style='width:10%') Price
        th(style='width:8%') Quantity
        th.text-center(style='width:22%') Subtotal
        th(style='width:10%')
    tbody
        tr
        td(data-th='Product')
            .row
            .col-sm-2.hidden-xs
                img.img-responsive(src='http://placehold.it/100x100', alt='...')
            .col-sm-10
                h4.nomargin Product 1
                p
                | Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        td(data-th='Price') $1.99
        td(data-th='Quantity')
            input.form-control.text-center(type='number', value='1')
        td.text-center(data-th='Subtotal') 1.99
        td.actions(data-th='')
            button.btn.btn-info.btn-sm
            i.fa.fa-refresh
            button.btn.btn-danger.btn-sm
            i.fa.fa-trash-o
        tr
        td(data-th='Product')
            .row
            .col-sm-2.hidden-xs
                img.img-responsive(src='http://placehold.it/100x100', alt='...')
            .col-sm-10
                h4.nomargin Product 2
                p
                | Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        td(data-th='Price') $3.99
        td(data-th='Quantity')
            input.form-control.text-center(type='number', value='1')
        td.text-center(data-th='Subtotal') 3.99
        td.actions(data-th='')
            button.btn.btn-info.btn-sm
            i.fa.fa-refresh
            button.btn.btn-danger.btn-sm
            i.fa.fa-trash-o
    tfoot
        tr.visible-xs
        td.text-center
            strong Total 1.99
        tr
        td
            a.btn.btn-warning(href='#')
            i.fa.fa-angle-left
            |  Continue Shopping
        td.hidden-xs(colspan='2')
        td.hidden-xs.text-center
            strong Total $1.99
        td
            a.btn.btn-success.btn-block(href='#')
            | Checkout 
            i.fa.fa-angle-right
```

Comment: What url do you think you are exposing for the shopping cart?

Comment: /shoppingcart. Its routed js script is called cart.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting the /shoppingcart/shoppingcart endpoint? That's what you are exposing. If you only want to expose /shoppingcart then you want to mount the route in cart.js at /:

```
// GET cart page. router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
res.render('cart', { title: 'Shopping cart' }); });
```

You are repeating the route again in the code you posted:

```
router.get('/shoppingcart'...
```

Comment: Besides the // GET . Which i have tried both / and /shoppingcart. Still get the 404 error

Comment: O i see. Thanks. i think i found the problem. I just noticed that when i open the link . it routes to /shoppingcart.html , instead of just /shoppingcart. Of couse i have no idea why that’s happening, but at-least the route is working now.